# Google Analtyics Event Tracking for File Downloads Not Working

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to setup event tracking for file downloads in Google Analytics. After some research I added the following code to the link that needs to be tracked:

```
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Download','PDF',this.href]);" href="http://www.link.com/file.pdf" target="_blank">Link Text</a>
```

The following code is on the page for Google Analytics:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-9999999-1");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}
</script>
```

This has been active for over 48 hours but I'm not getting events in GA. It says that "13 of your visits sent events" but displays no other information. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're mixing two different APIs for Google Analytics.

The first snippet you posted is for the ASYNC tracking but you have used the (now legacy) traditional tracking in the second snippet.

To get it working change your page tracking code to look like this, the other code looks OK.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var _gaq = _gaq || [];
   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

   (function() {
     var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async =    true;
     ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +  '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

More details here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking

Answer (score 1):

If you are Migrating to Async Tracking, the following link can guide you - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples